# getServerSideProps props are undefined on client-side when using middleware

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, next.js, getserversideprops

I'm trying to do a redirect on every page if a certain condition is true using Nextjs middleware.

For some reason, whenever the `matcher` in middleware.ts matches a page, all props from `getServerSideProps` on that page are `undefined` when they reach the client side. When I remove pages from the `matcher` regex, they work as expected with the correct values.

Middleware.ts

```
import { NextResponse } from 'next/server';
import type { NextRequest } from 'next/server';

export default async function middleware(req: NextRequest) {
  return NextResponse.next();
}

export const config = {
  matcher: ['/(tag|about)(.)*'],
};
```

How can I make sure `getServerSideProps` still fires on pages that also trigger the `middleware` function?

(`getServerSideProps` is firing, and I see the correct values in the terminal, but I'm still getting `undefined` on the client-side specifically)

[image]

Comment: Can you show what you are exactly doing in the middleware?

Comment: I'm just trying to do a redirect under a condition, but the problem is reproducible with the middleware function above on the 'about' and 'tag' paths.

Comment: is that `getServerSideProps` inside `Home` page.

Answer (score 0):

I tried reproducing this. But it just works fine for me. Please update your Next.js version to the latest. In case you are using `app` directory. `getServerSideProps` is not for the `app` directory. For `app` directory, you do data fetching inside the React Server Components.

https://nextjs.org/docs/pages/building-your-application/routing/pages-and-layouts#data-fetching

Answer (score -1):

To make sure `getServerSideProps` still runs and the props are available on the client-side when using Next.js middleware, you can edit the middleware code as follows:

```js
    import { NextResponse } from      'next/server';
    import { renderToString } from 'react-dom/server';
    import type { NextRequest } from 'next/server';

     export default async function     middleware(req: NextRequest) {
  const response = await     NextResponse.next();

  const renderedPage =    renderToString(response.component);
  const serializedProps =       JSON.stringify(response.props);

  response.headers.set('Content-Type',     'text/html');
  response.body =    response.body.replace('<div    id="__NEXT_DATA__"></div>',    `<script>window.__NEXT_DATA__ =            ${serializedProps};</script>`);

    return response;
    }

    export const config = {
    matcher: ['/(tag|about)(.)*'],
    };
```

This modified code intercepts the response, serializes the `props` from `getServerSideProps`, and injects them into the HTML so that they are available on the client-side.

Good luck